# Предложное управление с нарицательным, ставшим именем собственным

Tags: управление

Если речь идёт о заведении общественного питания с названием "Центральный рынок", а не о рынке как таковом, необходимо употреблять предлог "в" в следующей конструкции: мы идём в "Центральный рынок"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлог ***в*** уместен при названии точки общепита, какое бы имя она не носила, в том числе и "Центральный Рынок". Подразумевая ресторан, говорим: *в «Русское Подворье»*, *в «Русское Поле»*, *в «Балтику»*, *в «Остров»*, *в «Дрова»*, *в «Казбек»*.